# Python change self to inherited class

Tags: python, class, oop, superclass, self

I have this kind of structure:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, val1):
        self.val1 = val1

    def changeToGoo(self)
        HOW???

class Goo(Foo):
    def __init__(self, val1, val2):
        super(val1)
        self.val2 = val2

a = Foo(1)
a.changeToGoo()
```

'a' is now an instance of Foo
now i would like to change it to be an instance of Goo, by using the method "changeToGoo",  and add the other value.

How can this be done in Python?

I have tried:

```
self.__class__ = Goo
```

but when I check:

```
type(a)
```

it's still Foo, and not Goo.

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Please elaborate why you want to do that.

Comment: You should never need to cast a superclass to one of its subclasses, it's a sign of a design flaw.

Comment: @SimeonVisser That's not true. In particular, it can be appropriate during, for example, deserialisation.

Comment: @Marcin: could you give an example? I would imagine you'd want to construct the class again at the other end so why would it need to become a subclass prior to deserialisation?

Comment: @SimeonVisser (1) Deserialisation is the process of constructing instances from the serialisation format. It *is* the process of constructing the object again at the other end. (2) As you deserialise, you usually find a type tag. It can be more efficient to change type, rather than allocating a new object at that point.

Comment: @Marcin isn't that choosing a subclass based on what you need to do? In other words: you make a decision and you instantiate once. That's not the same as instantiating a class and only then casting down to one of the subclasses, as in this question.

Comment: @SimeonVisser No, it can make sense to instantiate once, then cast down. Obviously, it depends on the format, and the constraints of the environment. It's more common in C++ to do that (using in place `new`), but the same reasons could apply in Python. I bet they don't apply to OP's problem, but it's not a "never" thing.

Comment: @Marcin that's fair, I agree that using "never" was strong. I haven't yet come across a need for it but it sounds like it needs to be done with care. For example, bad OOP design could also lead to the need for downcasting but that can be avoided.

Comment: Many folks think downcasting should be eschewed primarily because it's indicative of poor OO design, at least according to the [Wikipedia article about it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downcasting). I tend to agree.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Python 2, make `Foo` inherit from `object` to make it a new-style class instead:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __init__(self, val1):
...         self.val1 = val1
... 
>>> class Goo(Foo):
...     def __init__(self, val1, val2):
...         super(val1)
...         self.val2 = val2
... 
>>> f=Foo(1)
>>> f.__class__
<class '__main__.Foo'>
>>> f.__class__ = Goo
>>> f
<__main__.Goo object at 0x10e9e6cd0>
>>> type(f)
<class '__main__.Goo'>
```

Now you *can* change `self.__class__`. In a `changeToGoo()` method:

```
def changeToGoo(self)
    self.__class__ = Goo
    self.val2 = 'some value'
```

or re-use `__init__`:

```
def changeToGoo(self)
    self.__class__ = Goo
    self.__init__(self.val1, 'some value')
```

This does make your objects somewhat monstrous, in that they change identity. Shapeshifting is rarely a great idea. You may want to rethink your use case.

Comment: This is right, but the object should also undergo `__init__`ialisation for the subclass.

Answer (score 2):

You could do :

```
def changeToGoo(self, val2):
    return Goo(self.val1, val2)
```

Then call and assign, adding the extra attribute

```
a = a.changeToGoo(val2)
```